# java inheritance: in the parent method write code that uses child variable

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write a general GUI class that contains main methods used by all different and more specific GUIs.

```
public class GeneralGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea;
    protected void say(String s) {
        logTextArea.append(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

the subclass class contains:

```
public class SpecificGUI extends GeneralGUI {
    protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea;
    [...]
    private void initComponents() {
        [...]
        logTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    }
}
```

what I want is that when I call

```
SpecificGUI myGUI =  new SpecificGUI();
myGUI.say("Ciao!");
```

the `"Ciao!"` string is appended to `myGUI.logTextArea`, but this doesn't happen: it insteads throws a Null Pointer Exc because it is looking for the `logTextArea` belonging to GeneralGUI - an object that hasn't been instantiated.

1) why is it so?
2) how can I achieve the desider result?

thanks!

EDIT:
I have tried removing the variable declaration in the subclass: being it a GUI I designed through netbeans, netbeans won't let me remove the declaration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You've already answered the question — the `say()` method of the parent class it is looking for the `logTextArea` inside the parent class, where it is declared. Your re-declaration of the field in the child class creates another field, which hides the same-named field from the parent class.

2) Just remove the declaration of another `logTextArea` in child class.

If you really need another field in the child class with the same name, then you can access the (hidden) parent field via `super.logTextArea`.

Comment: 2) netbeans won't let me! I have created the GUI through netBeans: I had already tried removing the declaration of child field but since it was created within that class file I can't remove it!

Comment: ok i have simply removed the lines with another editor and it now works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to define

```
protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea
```

twice.

defining it as a protected field of parent class means all inhereting classes has access to this field.

inheritance works like this:

1) You call parent method foo() from child class B.

2) if child class has method foo() it is invoked

3) if child has no method foo look up the chain of inheritance for a method foo() and invoke it

4) say method foo() in parent class A uses field x, it can only access the field x if A or any super class has it.

Comment: thank you but netbeans won't let me remove the second declaration

Comment: what do you mean, what does it says? never used netbeans but this sounds really not reasonable

Comment: it does to me as well. However netbeans doesn't allow you to edit certain portions of code it has automatically generated.

Comment: I solved modifying them with another editor: net beans did not complain

Answer (score 1):

1-logTextArea  is not getting instantiated thats why you are getting  NPE.
2-You have to decide where you want logTextArea  as class attribute.i think it does not make any sense keeping it in both classes,else try and instantiate  logTextArea  of generalGUI class.

Comment: thank you but Netbeans doesn't allow me to remove the second declaration from the specific class since it is there where I have designed the GUI

Answer (score 1):

```
protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea
```

hides the member variable of parent class **GeneralGUI** and you haven't initialize logTextArea with nothing so it remains **Null** that's why you got **NullPointerEception**. You should just remove member variable **logTextArea** from **SpecificGUI** class

Comment: thanks but Netbeans won't let me! I have designed the Specific GUIs with netbeans and then simply factored all common variables withing more general class. Now if I try to edit the variable declaration NetBeans bites!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea in the child class.

Next in you parent protected javax.swing.JTextArea logTextArea is not defined and is null, it is a object and perhaps needs to be initiated prior to append. Please check.